# Implementing Feedback in R / Shiny with DT DataTables rows per select input choice not working / crashing

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I am trying to build a feedback system. Here is a simplified example what I am trying to build. I have a `DT:datatable` that is rendered with a feedback column, based on a selected input choice.

The feedback is submitted through the `observeEvent` on a submit button. All the UI and server components are mostly as I want.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- ui <- dashboardPage(
  header = dashboardHeader(title='Car Recommendations'),
  sidebar = dashboardSidebar(
    width = 450,
    fluidRow(
      column(
        width = 9,
        selectInput(
          "cyl", 'Select Cylinder Count:',
          choices = c('', sort(unique(mtcars$cyl)))
          )
        )
      )
    ),
  body = dashboardBody(
    fluidPage(
    fluidRow(
      uiOutput('rec_ui')
      ))
    )
  )

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  mtcarsData <- reactive({
    req(input$cyl)
    mtcars %>%
      filter(cyl == input$cyl) %>%
      select(am, wt, hp, mpg)
  })
  
  output$rec_ui <- renderUI({
    mtcarsData()
    mainPanel(
      actionButton(
        'feedbackButton', 'Submit Feedback', class = 'btn-primary'
      ),
      dataTableOutput(('rec')),
      width = 12
    )
  })
  
  feedbackInputData <- reactive({
    mtcars <- mtcarsData()
    recsInput <- sapply(1:nrow(mtcars), function(row_id)
      input[[paste0('rec', row_id)]]
    )
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$feedbackButton, {
    mtcars <- mtcarsData()
    
    feedbackInput <- feedbackInputData()
    recFeedbackDf <- bind_rows(
      lapply(1:nrow(mtcars), function(row_id)
        list(
          shiny_session_token = session$token,
          recommendation_type = 'CAR',
          input_cyl = input$cyl,
          recommended_mpg = mtcars$mpg[row_id],
          recommendation_feedback = feedbackInput[row_id],
          feedback_timestamp = as.character(Sys.time())
        )
      )
    )
    
    write.table(
      recFeedbackDf, 'feedback.csv', row.names = FALSE,
      quote = FALSE, col.names = FALSE, sep = '|',
      append = TRUE
    )
    showModal(
      modalDialog(
        'Successfully submitted', easyClose = TRUE,
        footer = NULL, class = 'success'
      )
    )
  })
  
  output$rec <- DT::renderDataTable({
    df <- mtcarsData()

    feedbackCol <- lapply(1:nrow(df), function(recnum)
      as.character(
        radioButtons(
          paste0('rec', recnum), '',
          choices = c('neutral' = 'Neutral', 'good' = 'Good', 'bad' = 'Bad'),
          inline = TRUE
        )
      )
    )
    feedbackCol <- tibble(Feedback = feedbackCol)
    
    df <- bind_cols(
      df,
      feedbackCol
    )
    
    df %>%
      DT::datatable(
        extensions = 'FixedColumns',
        rownames = FALSE,
        escape = FALSE,
        class="compact cell-border",
        options = list(
          pageLength = 10,
          lengthChange = FALSE,
          scrollX = TRUE,
          searching = FALSE,
          dom = 't',
          ordering = TRUE,
          fixedColumns = list(leftColumns = 2),
          preDrawCallback = JS(
            'function() { Shiny.unbindAll(this.api().table().node()); }'
          ),
          drawCallback = JS(
            'function() { Shiny.bindAll(this.api().table().node()); } '
          ),
          autoWidth = TRUE,
          columnDefs = list(
            list(width = '250px', targets = -1)
          )
        )
      )
    })
  
  }

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

However, upon submission, one of two things happens:

1. App crashes with the following error in `write.table`. But, the root causes is that this line of code is returning a list of `NULL` values instead of my feedback inputs.

```
Warning: Error in write.table: unimplemented type 'list' in 'EncodeElement'
```

```
  feedbackInputData <- reactive({
    mtcars <- mtcarsData()
    recsInput <- sapply(1:nrow(mtcars), function(row_id)
      input[[paste0('rec', row_id)]]
    )
  })
```

2. When the app does not crash, and Feedback gets submitted, but the new inputs don't take effect. Only the first ever submission is repeated written to the CSV.

Any idea where I am going wrong with this app?

*Additional Info*: It is my hunch that the crash happens when I get from a selection from 'fewer rows' DT to more rows, and not the other way. For example, if I select 8 CYL first, which has more cars, and then 4, the app does not crash on submit. But the reverse, it does. BTW - in either case, my feedback does not get updated.

Comment: Any reason why you `renderUI` your `dataTableOutput` instead of putting it directly into the `UI`?  From what I see the `renderUI` part does not do any useful with the data, it just re-renders the table whenever the data changes, but it will always render to the same.

Comment: Because I am trying to display the feedback button and the table, only if data is present, via a reactive call and check. Anyway, that part of the code structure is not really relevant for my question or the reason it is not working.

Comment: It is not, but it over-complicates your question so it makes it so much more complicated to help you, as the error  is  somewhat obfuscated. A good reprex is also minimal. In your reprex it is for example quite a task to even name all the `inputs` as they are noth created on the `ui` and the `server` side. All I am saying is that you have higher chance to get help, if you make your example simpler.

Comment: I can't see the output table. The app just shows the selectInput and the feedback button. The `datatable` is never rendered. But when hitting the feedback button I do get the same error (always). The reason is that the column `recommendation_feedback` is a list-column containing `NULL`s. `write.table` does not support list-columns.

Comment: I am aware of that, and noted in my post. I am trying to make it NOT return a list of nulls. Also, the table renders fine for me. Not sure if there is a version issue.

Comment: I don't have a solution for this question but the app returns an error from 2nd selection of dropdown. It finds `input$rec1` and `input$rec2` for the 1st time, these values return `NULL` after that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid the app from crashing write the line

`recFeedbackDf <- apply(recFeedbackDf,2,as.character)`

just before `write.table()`

Please note that `lapply` returns a list, hence your first issue.

Next, recycling input IDs in radio buttons is also an issue.  By defining unique IDs, you can make it work.   Lastly, to ensure that the radio buttons work all the time, it is best to define new IDs.  If the IDs are fixed for a given `cyl` value, it will only work the first time. Subsequent selection of that `cyl` will display the initial selection, which can be updated via `updateradioButtons`, but that will not be reactive.  Try this and modify display table to your needs.

```
library(DT)
library(data.table)
library(shiny)
#library(shinyjs)
library(shinydashboard)
options(device.ask.default = FALSE)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  header = dashboardHeader(title='Car Recommendations'),

  sidebar = dashboardSidebar(
    width = 450,
    fluidRow(
      column(
        width = 9,
        selectInput(
          "cyl", 'Select Cylinder Count:',
          choices = c('', sort(unique(mtcars$cyl)))
        )
      )
    )
  ),
  body = dashboardBody(
    #useShinyjs(),
    fluidPage(
      fluidRow(
        actionButton('feedbackButton', 'Submit Feedback', class = 'btn-primary'),
        DTOutput('rec'),
        verbatimTextOutput("sel")
      ))
  )
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {
  cntr <- reactiveVal(0)
  rv <- reactiveValues()
  mtcarsData <- reactive({
    mtcar <- mtcars %>% filter(cyl == input$cyl) %>% 
      select(cyl, am, wt, hp, mpg) 
  })

  observe({
    req(input$cyl,mtcarsData())
    
    mtcar <- mtcarsData()
    id <- cntr() 
    m = data.table(
      rowid = sapply(1:nrow(mtcar), function(i){paste0('rec',input$cyl,i,id)}),
      Neutral = 'Neutral',
      Good = 'Good',
      Bad = 'Bad',
      mtcar
    ) %>%
    mutate(Neutral = sprintf('<input type="radio" name="%s" value="%s" checked="checked"/>', rowid, Neutral),
           Good = sprintf('<input type="radio" name="%s" value="%s"/>', rowid, Good),
           Bad  = sprintf('<input type="radio" name="%s" value="%s"/>', rowid, Bad)
           )

    rv$df <- m
    
    print(id)
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$cyl, {
    cntr(cntr()+1)
    #print(cntr())
  },ignoreInit = TRUE)

  feedbackInputData <- reactive({
    dfa <- req(rv$df)
    list_values <- list()
    for (i in unique(dfa$rowid)) {
      list_values[[i]] <- input[[i]]
    }
    list_values
  })

  observeEvent(input$feedbackButton, {
    req(input$cyl)
    mtcar <- rv$df  ## this could be mtcarsData(), if picking columns not in rv$df but only in mtcarsData()
    dt <- rv$df

    dt$Feedback  <- feedbackInputData()  
    recFeedbackDf <- bind_rows(
      lapply(1:nrow(mtcar), function(row_id){
        list(
          shiny_session_token = session$token,
          recommendation_type = 'CAR',
          input_cyl = input$cyl,
          recommended_mpg = mtcar$mpg[row_id],
          recommendation_feedback = dt$Feedback[row_id],
          feedback_timestamp = as.character(Sys.time())
        )
      })
    )

    recFeedbackDf <- apply(recFeedbackDf,2,as.character)

    write.table(
      recFeedbackDf, 'feedback.csv', row.names = FALSE,
      quote = FALSE, col.names = FALSE, sep = '|',
      append = TRUE
    )
    showModal(
      modalDialog(
        'Successfully submitted', easyClose = TRUE,
        footer = NULL, class = 'success'
      )
    )
  })
  
  output$rec <- renderDT(
    datatable(
      rv$df,
      selection = "none",
      escape = FALSE,
      options = list(
        columnDefs = list(list(visible = FALSE, targets = c(0,4))),  ## not displaying rowid and cyl 
        dom = 't',
        paging = FALSE,
        ordering = FALSE
      ),
      callback = JS(
        "table.rows().every(function(i, tab, row) {
                    var $this = $(this.node());
                    $this.attr('id', this.data()[0]);
                    $this.addClass('shiny-input-radiogroup');
                  });
                  Shiny.unbindAll(table.table().node());
                  Shiny.bindAll(table.table().node());"
      ),
      rownames = F
    ),
    server = FALSE
  )
  
  ###  verify if the radio button values are being returned
  output$sel = renderPrint({
    req(feedbackInputData())
    feedbackInputData()
  })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: That is actually not my problem. The `sapply` as I indicated is supposed to return a vector, but is returning a list of NULLs because I am doing something wrong in recycling the input IDs for the next DT feedback column. The issue is not with `write.table`. And converting to `as.character()` does nothing but fill my feedback with NULLs. Not what the user input.

Comment: Preventing the crash is not my need, as I already know what is causing the crash, and explained in the question. I want to resolve the root cause of the crash.

Comment: Feedback is working now - define new set of IDs for each display.

Comment: Interesting - when `paging = TRUE` does not work. It tries to submit feedback for first page only, and clearly fails since the original displayed table's `nrow` mismatch with the `length` of the list. Any ideas on how to make this work along with `paging = TRUE`?